# Change item foreground color of QSortFilterProxyModel without modifying source model

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, pyqt

I have a QStandardItemModel with multiple views and proxy models linked up to it. In some of the table views I want to change the color of the text, for example graying-out rows or highlighting rows a unique color.

If I call `proxy_model.setData(index, QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0), QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.ForegroundRole)` on a proxy model this of course changes the color, but it modifies the source model, which effects all other proxy models - which I don't want.

I realize that a QIdentityProxyModel is made for this sort of thing, however because I already am using proxy models (can you stack them?) and I do still want to keep editing ability, that doesn't work for me.

So is there some way of 'overriding' the ForegroundRole only in a proxy model?

Comment: Yes, you can "stack" proxy models. But if you want to change the behavior only of the proxy, then you need to subclass it, override both `data()` and `setData()` and keep track of the changes in that model.

Comment: Sounds... cumbersome. Is there a way of blocking the proxy model from changing the source model's data? If I subclassed the `setData()` method and had it filter out foregroundrole, is that possible?

Comment: You do realize that views and other proxy models always use `data()` to access the model, don't you? At the same way, `setData()` is what's called on models to update contents, including what proxies do to update their sources. You must keep track of the changes that you're not going to pass to the source model, because otherwise, if you just "filter out" those changes, they will be lost. It's not cumbersome, it's quite obvious.